# Google analytics track dynamically generated pdfs

Tags: php, google-analytics, pdf-generation

I have a script that generates pdfs dynamically based on different parameteres passed via GET.
The urls looks like `www.mydomain.com/generate_pdf.php/?entry_ids=1,3,5,6&orderby=ASC` etc

How can I track those urls with GA?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I could have GA code in the generate_pdf.php but then how can I output the pdf?

This is the code I have now in generate_pdf.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
generate_pdf();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup an event tracking if you want to track links which do not have GA embedded on the landing page. You could define for example the the event with:

- category: Download
- action: PDF
- label: 1,3,5,6

Resulting in your link code to appear something like this:

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com/generate_pdf.php/?entry_ids=1,3,5,6&orderby=ASC" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'PDF', '1,3,5,6']);">Download PDF</a>
```

For more information how to setup event tracking, have a look at the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).